# C++ - Thread Argument getting incremented for no reason

Tags: c++, linux, multithreading, arguments

My problem is related to the following code:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <unistd.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
#include <iostream>
#include <pthread.h>
#include <sys/types.h>
#include <arpa/inet.h>
#include <sys/socket.h>
#include <netinet/in.h>

int connections[100];
int connectionCounter = 0;
pthread_t clientHandlerThread;

void *ClientHandlerThread(void *index) {
        int id = *reinterpret_cast<int*>(index);
        char buffer[256];
        while(true) {
                recv(connections[id-1], buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                for(int i = 0; i < connectionCounter; i++) {
                        if(i == (id-1))
                                continue;
                        send(connections[i], buffer, sizeof(buffer), 0);
                }
        }
}

int main() {
        sockaddr_in addr;
        int addrlen = sizeof(addr);
        addr.sin_addr.s_addr = inet_addr("127.0.0.1");
        addr.sin_port = htons(1111);
        addr.sin_family = AF_INET;

        int sListen = socket(AF_INET, SOCK_STREAM, 0);
        bind(sListen, (sockaddr*)&addr, addrlen);
        listen(sListen, SOMAXCONN);

        int newConnection;
        for (int i = 0; i < 100; i++) {
                newConnection = accept(sListen, (sockaddr*)&addr, (socklen_t*)&addrlen);
                if (newConnection == 0) {
                        std::cout << "Failed to accept the client's connection." << std::endl;
                }
                else {
                        char MOTD[256] = "Welcome! This is the Message of the Day.";
                        send(newConnection, MOTD, sizeof(MOTD), 0);
                        connections[i] = newConnection;
                        connectionCounter++;
                        pthread_create(&clientHandlerThread, NULL, ClientHandlerThread, (void*)&i);
                }
        }

        return 0;
}
```

This is just a simple TCP server (this is only a test project to understand sockets under Linux, since they are different under Windows) which causes me quite a problem, although this can also be a simple understanding problem.

My problem: I start the server (compiled with G++, Debian Stretch 64 bit, g++ main. cpp -o server -lpthread) and connect to 2 clients. Works so far, but I can only send a message from one client, not the other. I found the problem in the "ClientHandlerThread" function. The argument "index" is cast into an int, but it is getting incremented by +1. That means my ID is not 1 (as it should be, because there are only 2 clients and it starts with 0) but 2.

Do I have some sort of understanding problem? I'm just starting to write C++ under Linux, maybe I have a problem with the threads.

Thanks for help!

Comment: Perhaps the concept you're missing is that threads share the same memory?

Comment: On an unrelated note: The `accept` function return `-1` on error, not `0` (which is a valid socket descriptor value).

Comment: Yeah of course, I knew it's -1 but I wrote 0, don't ask me why :P Thanks for the hint.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You pass a pointer to the very same variable to *all* threads. If you're quick enough to connect two (or more clients) two or more threads could get the same value from the dereference of that pointer.

This is one of the very few cases where it's usuallyconsidered okay to cast an integer value to a pointer and back.

First in the call to `pthread_create` use `(void *) (intptr_t) i`. Then in the thread function do `int id = (int) (intptr_t) index`.

---

Or, since you program in C++, you could use [`std::thread`](http://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/thread/thread) instead, which allows you to pass arguments *by value* instead.

Comment: Hey, you solved my problem. It was actually a stupid mistake of mine. Under Windows I passed the value of the variable and not a pointer to it. When I wanted to do it on Linux, it didn't work and I read on the internet that you had to pass a void pointer and convert it again. I knew that I used a pointer here, but because of the fact that it was running under Windows, I forgot that I hand over the address instead of the value itself. I'll look at std::thread later, thanks for the tip!

Answer (score 2):

You are reading content of `i` local variable from `main` function from multiple threads without any synchronization which leads to undefined behavior. You can pass index by value:

```
pthread_create(&clientHandlerThread, NULL, ClientHandlerThread, reinterpret_cast<void*>(static_cast<::std::intptr_t>(i)));

// in handler
int id = static_cast<int>(reinterpret_cast<::std::intptr_t>(index));
```

You should also rewrite program to perform proper cleanup: make some condition for threads to exit and call `pthread_join` for all spawned threads.